# DirectX9 - swap chain filled?

Tags: direct3d, directx-9

I use triple buffering and don't generate frames continuously. But when I do, they need to be exactly timed. To ensure that a certain frame is displayed at a certain time, I need to know how many (of the two) buffers are waiting to be displayed in the swap chain (`IDirect3DSwapChain9`) as it delays the frame I draw next. Is there any possibility to obtain if the swap chain is empty or filled thus will block me on next present call?